# Is it possible to disable clustering animations with DefaultClusterRenderer and ClusterManager?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Using google maps api v2 for android and the Clustering library(renderer and manager) of [Google-Map-Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering).

Is it possible to turn off the animations when two or more markers are clustered together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can turn off animation. I asume you have Google-Map_Utils project referenced. It is controled by a private boolean field SHOULD_ANIMATE in the DefaultClusterRenderer.java in com.google.maps.android.clustering.view package.

Steps to do:

- Open DefaultClusterRenderer.java in com.google.maps.android.clustering.view package;
- Find the following line:

> private static final boolean SHOULD_ANIMATE = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;

- Simply set the value of SHOULD_ANIMATE variable to false:

> private static final boolean SHOULD_ANIMATE = false;

Comment: i wonder wth they declared it as private if it is expected that developer will want to be able affect it.. this is stupidity. how can i affect it without editing code now? it seems i cant. Copy decompiled class and save it as my class.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of the Google-Map-Utils, there is a public method

```
renderer.setAnimation(false)
```